# Grunt Deployments /bin/sh: mysql: command not found

Tags: mysql, node.js, shell, gruntjs, command-line-interface

I'm beginning to use Grunt.js to manage my workflow for repeated tasks and right now I'm stuck on database deployment (a huge source of potential errors for me).

I've installed the grunt-deployment package and I can pull down the remote database, as well as push to it (theoretically). However locally I get the error:

```
/bin/sh: mysql: command not found
```

Or

```
/bin/sh: mysqldump: command not found
```

I'm not sure where I should be adding those commands, or how. I'm also using AMPPS for my local development.

The environment I'm in is Mac OS X, using AMPPS as my apache/mysql server.

Comment: please tell us about your deployment target (os/setup etc.). are you using a mysql package or custom install? do you have the mysql-client package installed?

Comment: I've edited the question but will include here. The environment I'm in is Mac OS X, using AMPPS as my apache/mysql server. I do not have the mysql-client package installed and do not know how to do that with my current set up. Although I'll now research starting there.

Comment: are you running the command as a privileged user?

Comment: in that case not really a grunt but an ampps setup problem - look here http://superuser.com/questions/364215/how-to-keep-php-and-mysql-of-ampps-as-default-in-macosx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put AMPPS MySQL in PATH environment and all should be fine.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin
```